# Can we and how to open a new window and closes the previous window in the same thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am asking this, because i want to know if when we are running an app, for start if we have an window to authenticate like a Log In window, after validating the user, can we open the Main Window in the same Thread without creating a new one?

I am trying to do this in WPF, but i think that is same thing in WPF or in Windows Forms.

Comment: WPF and C# are not mutually exclusive things -.-

Comment: @H.B. - he might mean XAML vs C#.

Comment: @ChrisF Actually, i think WPF vs. Winforms makes more sense here.

Comment: Yes, i have confused myself in the explanation, i was trying to say that i think that is the same way in WPF and in Windows Forms. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate a Windows Forms application via the IDE, it will generate the code for one form, as well as a *Main* function that displays the form at runtime. You can rewrite the *Main* method so it displays one form modally then displays the next form.

But there's a simpler way to achieve your objectives:

Have two windows: your Main window, where most of the work is done, and the login screen.

In the OnLoad event of your main window, create an instance of your login window and call ShowModal() on this instance.

If the login fails, then exit the application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
Just do it.

Comment: Just call `Close()` and `Show()`.

Comment: Ok i tried and it works in WPF, but in Windows Forms doesn't work by that way. So how i can do it in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

This question does not offer enough context to tell you how to do this in your specific case. In general you can just `Close()` a window, construct a new one and call `Show()` on it.

You should make sure the `Application.ShutdownMode` does not kill off your application when the window is closed though.

Comment: By opening the new window after closing the first one, works in WPF. I tried and it works, but doesn't work in Windows Forms. So i have wrote this question, either way i want to know how to do it in Windows Forms...

Comment: See Andrew Shepherd's answer for Winforms.